# What are these files in my flash drive?

Tags: usb-drive, root, drive

These files are on my USB flash drive. I can't view them with Dolphin, but I can view them in the terminal. I tried to copy them, but I failed? Virus? Is it OK to format the USB flash drive completely if I can?

[image]

Comment: what was the command you used in the terminal? it looks like you did `ls /dev` which isn't your flash drive but the root device location. your flash drive should be mounted at `/media/$USER/flashdrivename` in 13.04 or `/media/flashdrivename` in earlier versions of ubuntu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those aren't the files on your USB, those are the devices attached to your system (sda, sdb, sdc are disks, sda1 is the partition 1 of disk 1 and so on)

If you want to see the contents of your usb you must locate it there (or use `lsblk` command) and mount it for example with:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdc1 /mnt
```

Where `/dev/sdc1` is your device / partition and `/mnt` is your mountpoint.

Once you have the mountpoint (in this case `/mnt`) you could list the files in it by doing one of the followings:
`ls /mnt` or `cd /mnt && ls`

Read more at: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/gutsy/en/man8/mount.8.html

Comment: "sudo mount /dev /sdd1 mnt" then "ls" shouldn't these two show folders in it?

Comment: I forgot the `ls` command. I edited it :)

Comment: Anyway, you should do `sudo mount /dev/sdd1 /mnt` if you want to mount `/dev/sdd1` to `/mnt`.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the other answer. Looks like these are devices & a few apps like alarm on the system. If it's nothing you need on that flashdrive, you should format it just to be safe since you said you cleared few viruses. 
On windows goto start->type diskpart & select diskpart.exe

Type List Disk, Select your Flash Drive with(Select Disk # ) then type the following the the provided order:

1. clean
2. create partition primary
3. select partition
4. active
5. format fs=fat32
6. wait for the format to complete
7. type assign
8. type exit

Don't know much about ubuntu yet. So can't guide you in that yet